# “Expected token not present” error in my Apache log

Tags: cookies, apache2, mod-perl

My website runs on Apache 2 with mod_perl and uses the Mason template system. I am not using any authentication system or any sessions in my website, but sometimes (at random) I get this error:

> ## Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@admin.org
>   and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

In the error log, the corresponding record is:

```
[Mon Dec 19 09:34:26 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Expected token not present
```

Server version string:

```
Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) mod_apreq2-20051231/2.6.0 mod_perl/2.0.3 Perl/v5.8.8 Server
```

My browsers sends this weird cookie:

```
Name:                   BC_BANDWIDTH
Content:                1324486772745,6811
Domain:                 example.org
Path:                   /
Send For:               Any kind of connection
Accessible to Script:   Yes
Created:                Wednesday, December 21, 2011 12:59:09 PM
Expires:                When I close my browser
```

When I delete it, I can reload my page and it works. However after a couple of clicks the problem reappears.

**Why am I getting the error in my error log? How to fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

This is because of an invalid cookie set by some utilities on your app.

I faced the same problem and could not find "who" was setting the invalid cookie. So I had to edit Apache2/Cookie.pm. This is going to be the fix :

In the above pm, in the method/subroutine `fetch` you can see :

```
my $jar = $req->jar or return;
```

Just comment that line and insert this new line :

```
my $jar = eval {$req->jar()};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you omit the return statement in your solution, you had to circle the proceeding statement in an **eval** block as well. Otherwise you can expect a first time constellation where a function "cookie_class" is called on an undefined value what would throw an exception. Therefore

Replace additionally

```
$jar->cookie_class(__PACKAGE__);
```

with

```
eval {$jar->cookie_class(__PACKAGE__)};
```

Enjoy!